# Configure TLS for Sonarqube via Helm Chart

Tags: sonarqube, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I'm deploying Sonarqube via official helm charts and using following ingress configuration:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  # Used to create an Ingress record.
  hosts:
  - name: sonar.<company>.com
    # Different clouds or configurations might need /* as the default path
    path: /
    # For additional control over serviceName and servicePort
    # serviceName: someService
    # servicePort: somePort
    # the pathType can be one of the following values: Exact|Prefix|ImplementationSpecific(default)
    # pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "64m"

  # Set the ingressClassName on the ingress record
    # ingressClassName: nginx

  # Additional labels for Ingress manifest file
  #   labels:
  #    traffic-type: external
  #    traffic-type: internal
  tls:
  # Secrets must be manually created in the namespace. To generate a self-signed certificate (and private key) and then create the secret in the cluster please refer to official documentation available at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#tls-secrets
  - secretName: sonar-server-tls
    hosts:
    - sonar.<company>.com
```

Sonar is working when using: `http://sonar.<company>.com:443` but without the certificate. `https://sonar.<company>.com` doesnt work. I cannot find much related to this specific topic. Some questions:
Do I have to use nginx here? If yes, is it recommended to use `nginx.enabled: true` to make stuff working smooth? That secret name is valid, exists and its found during deployment.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTP instead of HTTPS is not recommended, as it will not provide the same level of security. It is possible to use Nginx to enable HTTPS,you will likely need to use nginx to act as a reverse proxy for the sonar..com domain, and then configure it to use the secret containing the certificate. It is generally recommended to use Nginx's nginx.enabled: true option to ensure that the setup is working properly, which will then allow you to set up the nginx configuration and use the secret name provided.. Once this is done, you should be able to access Sonar securely on the HTTPS address you specified.

For more information follow this [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#tls-secrets).

Comment: Thanks Sai for your answer. When I tried nginx.enabled=true, I started to get notification about breaking Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write rule. Is there a way to configure this the way there won't be any change on public IP addresses?

Comment: configure the nginx-ingress-controller deployment in your Kubernetes cluster with the --publish-service flag. This flag will ensure that the nginx-ingress-controller does not create a public IP address, but instead uses the IP address of the service to which it is assigned. Additionally, you may need to configure the serviceNetwork field in the Ingress resource to ensure that the nginx-ingress-controller can access the service.Follow this [git link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3033).